# Calculation of heat flux through a wall: time until temperature is reached?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics

A plate with a constant temperature $T_{p}$ is put against a wall. On the other side of the wall, the temperature $T_{i}(t)$ is measured.

[image]

Assuming $T_{i}(t=0)\neq T_{p} $, how long will it take until the following condition is met:

$T_{i}(t) = \frac{T_{i}(t=0) + T_{p}}{2}  $

The following conditions apply:

- There are no constraints on $T_{i}$
- No energy is transferred to the right side of $T_{i}$
- The heat throughout the wall (grey) is homogenous

The formula to calculate the heat transfer is

$\dot Q(t)=λ_{m} ⋅ s ⋅ A ⋅(T_{p}−T_{i}(t))$

where

$λ_{m}$ = thermal conductivity

$A$ = wall area

$T_{i}$ = wall temperature

$T_{p}$ = plate temperature

$s$ = wall thickness

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried so far?

Comment: Are there any constraints on $T_i$?

Comment: There are no constraints on $T_{i}$.

Comment: @Gert I've extended the original post to include a formula. I really don't know how to calculate this from there, cause I'm bad at math

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a case of *transient heat conduction*, in a quasi-$\text{1D}$ geometrical situation, where [Fourier's heat equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal_conduction#Transient_conduction) applies:

$$\frac{\partial T}{\partial t}=\alpha \frac{\partial^2 T}{\partial x^2}\tag{1}$$

where $\alpha=\frac{k}{\rho c_p}$

You also need boundary conditions and an initial condition.

Assume the wall to reach from $x=0$ to $x=S$, then:

$$T(t,0)=T_p$$

Because there's no heat conduction past the point $x\geq S$:

$$\Big(\frac{\partial T}{\partial x}\Big)_{x=S}=0$$

For the initial condition we can choose:

$$T(0,x)=T_i(0)$$

Now, as this is clearly a homework question, I have to leave the solving of $(1)$ to you.

---

Note that the equation:

$$\dot Q(t)=λ_{m}sA(T_{p}−T_{i}(t))$$

is incorrect. Heat flux due to conduction actually decreases with increasing thickness $s$.